# Remove data from arraylist of Objects

Tags: java, database, arraylist

So I have a program that is meant to store employee records such as ID#, name, start date, etc. When the user enter's an employee ID number and presses the remove button the arraylist should be searched and if that employee ID exists in the arraylist all of that employee's data should be deleted from the arraylist. I am able to add and display all of the data fine but I can't figure out how to search the arraylist for the ID number and then delete all of that employee's data. Any help with this would be appreciated. I have attached my code so far for the remove button, as well as some other code to show how the data is stored.

```
public class EmployeeRecords extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ArrayList <employees> employees = new ArrayList <employees>();
```

...

Remove button code:

```
private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int index;
    String id = idInput.getText();
    boolean idCheck = employees.contains(id);

    if (idCheck = true){
        index = employees.indexOf(id);
        employees.remove(index);
    }
    else {
        errorLabel.setText("Employee not found. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Add button code:

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    employees e;
    String id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate;

    id = idInput.getText();
    firstName = firstInput.getText();
    lastName = lastInput.getText();
    salary = salaryInput.getText();
    startDate = dateInput.getText();

    e = new employees(id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate);
    employees.add(e);
}
```

Employee Class:

```
class employees {
String id, firstName, lastName, salary, startDate;

employees (String _id, String _firstName, String _lastName, String _salary, String _startDate) {
    id = _id;
    firstName = _firstName;
    lastName = _lastName;
    salary = _salary;
    startDate = _startDate;
}
```

}

Comment: Does the `Employee` class override the `equals()` method?  If not, `contains()` won't work.  Also, using the same name for a class and a variable is very bad practice. Your `employees` class should be `Employee`.  Third, a `List` is not in any sense "associative".  For that you need a `Map` that associates a key with a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList <employees> employees = new ArrayList <employees>();
String id = idInput.getText();
boolean idCheck = employees.contains(id);
```

ArrayList of  objects definitely does not contain String id.

P.S. As Jim said either Employee class must override equals method which must compare only id (not good idea) or use Map<String,Employee> to keep your list. then you can simply call remove method and do not need to check is the key there or not.